# How to determine all the week numbers in a month with Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following problem: Given a **year** and a **month**, determine the week numbers that are contained in that particular month, i.e., October 2017 contains week numbers 39,40,41,42,43,44. **Caveat:** As a rule, week starts in Monday and ends in Sunday. I have a cumbersome code that does the trick but I would like to know if there is a more elegant or Pythonistic way of doing this.

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

def get_week_numbers_in_month(year,month):
    list_of_weeks = []
    initial_day   = 1
    ending_day    = calendar.monthrange(int(year),int(month))[1] #get the last day of month
    initial_week  = int(datetime(year,month,initial_day).isocalendar()[1])
    ending_week   = int(datetime(year,month,ending_day).isocalendar()[1]) 
    counter = initial_week
    while(counter <= ending_week):
        list_of_weeks.append(counter)
        counter += 1
    return list_of_weeks

print("Your month contains the following weeks:\n"+str(get_week_numbers_in_month(2017,10)))
# result: Your month contains the following weeks: 
# [39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44]
```

Comment: Which day is the first day of the first week in a given year?

Comment: Monday is the first day.

Comment: It's still too early to accept any answer. Let's wait to see if other people come up with a better one.

Comment: So, you want all weeks that have any days in the month, rather than weeks such that all their days are in the month?

Comment: I want all weeks that have any days in the month. For instance, October 1st was Sunday and this is week no. 39 and this week contains the days of September.

Comment: @AlejandroBR The first day of the first week in the year determines which side of december 31st the first week starts on; ISO standard declars that the first week starts is the week that contains the first wednesday (or thursday -- I don't recall exactly) of the year; i.e. the first week of the year may or may not start in the year that it's the first of. Also the last week may not contain december 31st. It's important to know if you want to know which weeks are contained in a month.

Comment: which ISO standard did you read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply return a [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range) and avoid the whole initializing process. Also, note that [`isocalendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isocalendar) returns a 3-tuple of integers:

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

def get_week_numbers_in_month(year,month):
    ending_day    = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1] #get the last day of month
    initial_week  = datetime(year, month, 1).isocalendar()[1]
    ending_week   = datetime(year, month, ending_day).isocalendar()[1]
    return range(initial_week, ending_week + 1)

print("Your month contains the following weeks:")
print(get_week_numbers_in_month(2017,10))
# range(39, 45)
```

If you really want to return a list, simply return `list(range(...))`

Answer (score 1):

My approach

```
from datetime import datetime
import calendar

def get_week_numbers_in_month(year, month) -> list:
    ending_day = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1]  # get the last day of month
    initial_week = datetime(year, month, 1).isocalendar()[1]
    ending_week = datetime(year, month, ending_day).isocalendar()[1]
    res = list(range(initial_week, ending_week + 1))
    if not res:
        week_num = 52 if initial_week != 53 else 53
        res = list(range(initial_week, week_num + 1)) + list(range(1, ending_week + 1))
    return res
```

Output

```
>>> print(get_week_numbers_in_month(2021, 1))
[52, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would have added this as a comment, but do not have enough reputation to do so...

It looks like the approved answer does not actually work for the month of December as it will sometimes spill over into week 1. Also, why is it adding a week to the end when it creates the range?

Accepted answer:

```
def get_week_numbers_in_month(year,month):
    ending_day    = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1] #get the last day of month
    initial_week  = datetime(year, month, 1).isocalendar()[1]
    ending_week   = datetime(year, month, ending_day).isocalendar()[1]
    return range(initial_week, ending_week + 1)

print(get_week_numbers_in_month(2019,12))
# range(48, 2)
print(list(get_week_numbers_in_month(2019,12)))
# []
```

You would actually need to add some additional logic to build the list yourself instead of using a [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range)

```
def get_week_numbers_in_month(year,month):
    ending_day    = calendar.monthrange(year, month)[1] #get the last day of month
    initial_week  = datetime(year, month, 1).isocalendar()[1]
    ending_week   = datetime(year, month, ending_day).isocalendar()[1]

    # Adding logic to build week list if month is December (12)
    if month = 12:
        week_list = []
        while week != ending_week:
            if week not in week_list:
                week_list.append(week)
            else:
                if week >= 52:
                    week = 1
                else:
                    week += 1
                week_list.append(week)
    else:
        week_list = list(range(initial_week, ending_week))
    return week_list

print(get_week_numbers_in_month(2019,12))
# [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 1]
```